# When we use delegate and Call back in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm very new on iOS application development so please explain me about delegate and call back. When we use use call back and delegate?

Comment: try this simple tutorial http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/

Comment: I would like to add a little bit of information to the links and answers below; use delegation for 1to1 relationships and notifications for 1toN relationships. E.g. one class tells another one that something has happened is a 1to1 and one class tells several others that something has happened is a 1toN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big piece about delegates here on the dev centre:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html

There is a tutorial app using callback/delegate

http://brandontreb.com/objective-c-programming-tutorial-creating-a-twitter-client-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

Call backs are used to allow an API or service to provide information to your code when certain events occur (e.g. when a task has completed). This is useful in asynchronous programming, e.g. when you want your current thread to get on with something else, or to allow the user to continue using the UI. (i.e. a call back is a function or lambda you have written, which is passed as a parameter to another method)

A delegate is the 'signature' (the 'type definition' of a method, including parameters) that a method (such as a call back) must provide in order for it to be useable as callback or event handler.

**Edit** Just to be complete, `Delegation` is also a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern), whereby the responsibility of control or action is delegated from one object to another.